# How to execute different recipes based on the output of a condition?

Tags: gnu-make

I am trying to compile all the source files except the one ones that are excluded.

Take into consideration that I can neither control the target nor the prerequisites, I can only control the recipe.

For some reason the if condition does not behave properly.

The first condition is always satisfied even if the output is true which happens when the source file is among the excluded files in custom_c_excludes variable, so the correct behavior should be that the ifep condition fails and the block preceding else should be executed.

(Condition output : true => don't compile it)

(Condition output : false => compile it)

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.$(OBJEXT): %.c
ifeq (false,$(if $(findstring $<,$(custom_c_excludes)),true,false))
    @echo 'This file is included and should be compiled.'
    @echo 'Condition output : $(if $(findstring $<,$(custom_c_excludes)),true,false)'
else
    @echo 'This file is not included  and should not be compiled.'
    @echo 'Condition output : $(if $(findstring $<,$(custom_c_excludes)),true,false)'

endif
```

The expected output is either :

> This file is included and should be compiled.
>
> Condition output : false

or

> This file is not included  and should not be compiled.
>
> Condition output : true

The actual output is :

> This file is included and should be compiled.
>
> Condition output : true

Comment: You cannot use automatic variables like `$<` inside make conditional statements like `ifeq`.  See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58713933/939557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifeq` is evaluated during parsing Makefile, not during execution of the recipe, so your recipe will always generate the same. You can verify it with `make -p`:

```
# Implicit Rules

obj/%.o: %.c
#  recipe to execute (from 'Makefile', line 11):
        @echo 'This file is included and should not be compiled.'
        @echo 'Condition output : $(if $(findstring $<,$(custom_c_excludes)),true,false)'
```

However, if you do know which files are to be evaluated differently (like this `custom_c_excludes` variable), you can do a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern), i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
OBJDIR := obj
OBJEXT := o

custom_c_excludes := foo.c

$(OBJDIR)/%.$(OBJEXT): %.c
        @echo 'This file is included and should be compiled.'

$(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.$(OBJEXT),$(custom_c_excludes)): $(OBJDIR)/%.$(OBJEXT): %.c
        @echo 'This file is not included and should not be compiled.'
```

Output:

```
$ make obj/foo.o
This file is not included and should not be compiled.

$ make obj/bar.o
This file is included and should be compiled.
```